# Preserve user input provided in script interaction even upon exiting script

Tags: shell, passwords, environment-variables, redhat-enterprise-linux

I'm running a script that interacts with different apps based on input supplied by user during interaction with script. While doing so, the user provides the assigned username/password that in turn is used by script to login to apps.

To reduce the need for a user to provide password every time he runs the script, I want to store it in memory as a variable, so that the password is available when the script exits and is available if the script is run by the user again within the same terminal.

The password variable should clear out when the user terminal exits. Also, I do not want to store the password in a file on HDD.

I tried using `export` but that doesn't work when the script exits.

OS : Linux RHEL 6 / 7

Answer (score 0):

We can use `export` to set the variable in script.

Now source the script and when it runs, the user provides the password as input which the script exports and sets it at shell level and it is retained even when the script completes/exits.

Next time when the script runs again within the same shell, we can get the variable details.

to source the script -->

```
bash$>. ./myscript  #Note the space after 1st DOT(.).
```

References:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30189/how-can-i-make-environment-variables-exported-in-a-shell-script-stick-around

https://askubuntu.com/questions/53177/bash-script-to-set-environment-variables-not-working

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14742358/preserve-environments-vars-after-shell-script-finishes

Answer (score 0):

Putting passwords (and other sensitive data) in scripts (or files, for that matter) is an *extremely bad idea*. Somebody who shouldn't run the command can grab the script and run it, and even filch the password to create havoc.

See if you can handle user authentication in some other way. If it is really needed in the first place, that is...

Comment: The user has to provide the password for the 1st time when he runs the scripts in a shell.. and the password in retained only in that shell and not any duplicate shells on same host. I've tested it.  I do agree with you, can you suggest any other ways to achieve my goal?